# When I enter a variable that is storing an object, it keeps returning the instance of that object rather than the list that I want it to

Tags: python, object

```
class Stack(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.stack = []

    def __str__(self):
        return self.stack

    def push(self, item):
        self.stack.append(item)

    def pop(self):
        popped = self.stack.pop()
        print(popped)

    def isEmpty(self):
        if len(self.stack) == 0:
            print("True")
        else:
            print("False")

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.stack)
```

I am trying to have the list returned when I call upon the object in interactive mode. This is what keeps happening:

```
>>> s = Stack()
>>> s.push("Plate 1")
>>> s.push("Plate 2")
>>> s.push("Plate 3")
>>> s
<__main__.Stack object at 0x0000017E06ED4E10>
```

Comment: The list is in `s.stack`. `s` is just an object without a `__repr__`.

Comment: Do you mean that you want the string representation to list the contents of your stack? In which case you should define `__repr__` on your class.

Comment: "I am trying to have the list returned when I call upon the object in interactive mode" - first, those words don't mean what you're trying to say. Second, what you're trying to do is a recipe for horrible confusion. It'd be better to display something like `Stack(['Plate 1', 'Plate 2', 'Plate 3'])`, with a constructor that accepts arguments like that.

Comment: When you type a variable in interactive mode it prints `repr(s)`, not `str(s)`.

Comment: The `__str__` method should always return a string.

Answer (score 1):

I think the methodology you may be looking for is documented here:
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables

Modified example code:

```
class Stack:
    stack_list = []
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def push(self, item):
        self.stack_list.append(item)
```

The 'push' method appends items to the 'stack_list' when it's called.

```
stack = Stack('the_stack')
stack.push('example1')
stack.push('example2')
stack.push('example3')
stack.stack_list
['example1', 'example2', 'example3']
```

Answer (score 0):

The Python interactive shell prints the representation, not the string, so you need to implement a `__repr__` method. But both `__str__` and `__repr__` should always return a string. So try:

```
def __str__(self):
    return str(self.stack)

def __repr__(self):
    return repr(self.stack)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest first to override `__repr__` instead of `__str__` to match your goal, however below you can find both approaches for the class:

```
class Stack(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.stack = []
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.stack)
    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.stack)
    def push(self, item):
        self.stack.append(item)
    def pop(self):
        popped = self.stack.pop()
        print(popped)
    def isEmpty(self):
        if len(self.stack) == 0:
            print("True")
        else:
            print("False")
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.stack)
```

Basically, what happened earlier you were triggering the representation of the object which is what you've called when you simply put `s`.

To have it transform to, let's say, a string representation you could do:

```
def __str__(self):
    return str(self.stack)
```

Analogously, you could do it for `__repr__`.

A example of its execution:

```
>>> s = Stack()
>>> print(s)
[]
>>> s.push(1)
>>> print(s) #this uses __str__
[1]
>>> s  #this uses __repr__
[1]
```

For deeper reference on the differences among them, you could check following thread [Difference between __str__ and __repr__?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/difference-between-str-and-repr)

Answer (score 0):

There are two things to note here:

1. When the REPL evals an object, it uses its `__repr__` method for presentation.
2. Your `__str__` method will cause errors because it does not return a string.

After running your code, the following behavior can be observed:

```
>>> s.stack
>>> ['Plate 1', 'Plate 2', 'Plate 3']
>>> print(s)
[...]
TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type list)
>>> repr(s)
>>> '<__main__.Stack object at 0x7fe358f7e240>'
```

To fix these issues, implement `__repr__`, for example like this:

```
def __repr__(self):
    return repr(self.stack)
```

Now

```
>>> s
>>> ['Plate 1', 'Plate 2', 'Plate 3']
```

shows the content of `s.stack`. In addition, you can remove the `__str__` method, because when printing, `__repr__` will be called as a fallback when there's no `__str__` implementation.

```
>>> del Stack.__str__
>>> print(s)
['Plate 1', 'Plate 2', 'Plate 3']
```

If you want to keep `__str__`, make sure to modify it in order to return a `str` object, otherwise you'll get a `TypeError` as demonstrated above.

---

A little more about `__repr__`:

Ideally, the method should return a string such that when copy pasted into the interpreter, an equal object will be built. Since your `__init__` method accepts no arguments, it's not possible here to display an informative string that would be evaluated as an instance of `Stack` and show the content of the stack at the same time.

If you changed `__init__` to

```
def __init__(self, iterable=None):
    if iterable is None:
        self.stack = []
    else:
        self.stack = list(iterable)
```

you could change `__repr__` to

```
def __repr__(self):
    return 'Stack({!r})'.format(self.stack)
```

which would look like this when implemented:

```
>>> s
>>> Stack(['Plate 1', 'Plate 2', 'Plate 3'])
```

... eval'ing this string would create a `Stack` with the same content.

---

While we're at it, consider implementing `__eq__` for good measure...

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    return isinstance(other, Stack) and self.stack == other.stack
```

... such that:

```
>>> s == eval(repr(s))
>>> True
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning the '`self.stack`' from the `__str__()` function, you can return the list as shown below:

```
class Stack(object):

def __init__(self):
    self.stack = []

def __str__(self):
    return str(list(plates for plates in self.stack))

def push(self, item):
    self.stack.append(item)

def pop(self):
    popped = self.stack.pop()
    print(popped)

def isEmpty(self):
    if len(self.stack) == 0:
        print("True")
    else:
        print("False")

def __len__(self):
    return len(self.stack)

s = Stack()
s.push("Plate 1")
s.push("Plate 2")
s.push("Plate 3")
print(s)
```

Output:

```
['Plate 1', 'Plate 2', 'Plate 3']
```

Comment: What's the point of calling `list()` on a list comprehension? And why do you need to make a copy when calling `str()`?

Comment: Yes, right. Returning str(self.stack) from __str__() function will also work.